# How do I toggle through array on the click?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am adding a slider where you can click on arrows and see the corresponding information pertaining to that click. When you click forwards, it works, but when you click on the other arrow it doesn't do anything. For the left arrow, I almost had the code working but if you click and extra time, it says uncaught TypeError and then both arrows refuse to work. Can anyone offer any advice.

Here's my code:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();



xhr.onload = function () {
    const episodes = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    let i = 1
    arrowRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (i < episodes.length) {
            epiNum.innerHTML = `Episode ${episodes[i].episode}`
            epiTitle.innerHTML = `${episodes[i].title}`;
            epiDescription.innerHTML = `${episodes[i].description}`;
            i++
            console.log(i)

        }
    })
    arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (i <= episodes.length) {
            i--
            epiNum.innerHTML = `Episode ${episodes[i].episode}`;
            epiTitle.innerHTML = `${episodes[i].title}`;
            epiDescription.innerHTML = `${episodes[i].description}`;
            console.log(i)
        }

    })
}

xhr.open('GET', 'data/episodes.json', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something that checks if you are at the end or beginning of the array.

```
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (i < episodes.length) {
        epiNum.innerHTML = `Episode ${episodes[i].episode}`
        epiTitle.innerHTML = `${episodes[i].title}`;
        epiDescription.innerHTML = `${episodes[i].description}`;
        if (i + 1 == episodes.length) {
          i = 0
        } else {
          i++
        }
        console.log(i)

    }
})
```

You'll have to do a similar check for the left arrow as well.

Also I think you'll want to change the value of I

```
let i = 0;
```